# Converting Data to a Dictionary From a CSV Without The First Row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, tuples

Suppose I have a CSV file that looks like the following:

```
Title,Category,Price,Rating
To Kill a Mockingbird,Fiction,11.99,89
Killing Lincoln,Nonfiction,15.99,85
```

And I want to convert it into a dictionary that looks like the following:

`{'To Kill a Mockingbird': ('Fiction', 11.99, 89), 'Killing Lincoln': ('Nonfiction', 15.99, 85), ... }`

***I want to make sure the titles of the columns are removed (i.e., the first row is NOT included).***

I started by trying the following.

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('bookdata.csv'))
result = {}

for row in reader:
    key = reader[0]
    result[key] = reader[1:]
print(result)
```

But when I do this, I don't successfully remove the first row, and the dictionary contains lists, not tuples. How can I fix this? I also want to make sure the **\n** character is stripped.

Comment: are those in different columns the csv or all in the same column separated by a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. First, there is a bug where you say `reader` when it should be `row`. Then its just a question of skipping the header line with `next` and converting a list to a tuple.

```
import csv
from decimal import Decimal

reader = csv.reader(open('bookdata.csv'))
# skip header
next(reader)
result = {}

for row in reader:
    # only needed if empty lines in input
    if not row:
        continue
    key = row[0]
    # Book with category, price in decimal, and other thingie??
    result[key] = row[1], Decimal(row[2]), int(row[3])

print(result)
```

Comment: is it possible to cast the numeric values as ints and floats during this process?

Comment: @324 - updated. I used `Decimal` instead of `float` because it looks like a dollar price and binary float is only an estimate of a decimal number. You can change that to float if you prefer, but there may be some loss in accuracy.

Comment: I tried this @tdelaney and it is still not working :( ```  books = {'To Kill a Mockingbird': ('Fiction', '11.99', '89'), 'Killing Lincoln': ('Nonfiction', '15.99', '85')}
from decimal import Decimal


for row in books:
    # only needed if empty lines in input
    if not row:
        continue
    key = row[0]
    # Book with category, price in decimal, and other thingie??
    books[key] = row[1], Decimal(row[2]), int(row[3])

print(books)   ```

Comment: I tried putting float instead and that didn't work either.